# jQuery: change Minutes into hour

Tags: jquery, input, time

I am using jQuery to convert minutes into hour, whenever minutes exceeds more than 59; hour is changed to 1.

I have tried this so far-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.minutes').change(function () {
            if ($('.minutes').val() > 59) {
                Math.floor($('.hour').val()) = ($(this).val()) + 1;
            }

        });
    });


</script>
```

Jsfiddle link- [Minutes into hour](http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/5wcaQ/6/)

I want minutes to show converted hour every time it exceeds multiplications of 60.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cased that minutes is more than 120, adding `1` doesn't produce the correct hour, instead of hard-coding the value by adding 1, you can divide the minutes by 60 and add the result to the `.hour` element's value.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.minutes').change(function () {
        var min = + this.value;
        if (min > 59) {
            this.value = min % 60;
            $('.hour').val(function (_, oldValue) {
                return +oldValue + Math.floor(min / 60);
            })
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GZEaH/

Answer (score 5):

here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/yKBWQ/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.minutes').change(function () {
        if ($('.minutes').val() > 59) {
            //Math.floor($('.hour').val() )= $(this).val() + 1;
            var min = $('.minutes').val();
            var hr = Math.floor(min / 60);
            var hrTemp = Math.floor($('.hour').val());
            var remMin = min % 60;
            $('.hour').val(hr + hrTemp);
            $('.minutes').val(remMin);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this is really just some basic math.

```
// get value
var minutes = parseInt($('.minutes').val());

// calculate
var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
minutes = minutes % 60;

// set new values
$('.hour').val(hours);
$('.minutes').val(minutes);
```

In case you dont know what `%` does: it's the [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)-operator:

> In computing, the modulo (sometimes called modulus) operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var hours = Math.floor( $('.minutes').val() / 60);          
var minutes = $('.minutes').val() % 60;


$('.hour').val(hours);
$('.minutes').val(minutes);    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.minutes').change(function () {
        if (parseInt($('.minutes').val()) > 59) {
            $('.hour').val($('.hour').val() + 1);
            $('.minutes').val(0);
        }

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stackmanoz/5wcaQ/1/

Answer (score 0):

Check sample code on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5wcaQ/9/

```
$('.minutes').change(function () {
            var minutes = parseInt($('.minutes').val());
            var hour = parseInt($('.hour').val() == '' ? '0' : $('.hour').val());
            var excessHour = parseInt(minutes / 60);
            minutes = minutes - (excessHour * 60);
            $('.minutes').val(minutes);
            excessHour += hour;
            $('.hour').val(excessHour);

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your minutes textbox value into hours. [ remember this code will not change the value of minutes textbox;  ]
http://jsfiddle.net/5wcaQ/12/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jqMin = $('.minutes'),
        jqHour = $('.hour');
    jqMin.change(function () {
        if ( jqMin.val() > 59) {
            console.log ( jqMin.val() + ' - ' + ( jqMin.val() / 60 ) );
            jqHour.val ( Math.floor ( jqMin.val() / 60 ) );
        }

    });
});
```